# How to Diable Ctrl + A and reuse Ctrl + A

Tags: wpf

`I use WPF
I want
case of ListBox : Ctrl + A is Disable
case of Textbox : Ctrl + A is Able

Example

xaml

```
<ListBox PriviewKeyDown = "privewKeyDown"\>
    <TextBox/\>
</ListBox\>
```

cs

```
private void priviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (Keyboard.Modifiers == ModifierKeys.Control)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.A)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

How to reuse Ctrl + A in TextBox?
Help

I try to use only one event PrivewKeyDown or KeyDown
May i use both event PrivewKeyDown and KeyDown
Event catch Two Time?`

Comment: What exactly do you mean? Do you want to handle Ctr+A globally? The TextBox already handles Ctrl+A by selecting all its content.

Comment: To be more specific, I want to turn off the Ctrl+a function in the Listbox and turn on the Ctrl+a function in TextBox

Comment: However, like the code posted above, PriviewKeyDown event in ListBox. e.Handled = true, Ctrl +a  is blocked. Not only ListBox But also TextBox. so I want to solve this problem

Comment: This means you have multi select enabled for the ListBox? By default Ctrl+A is not handled by the ListBox.

Comment: If you want to enable multi-select in the ListBox without the Ctrl+[x] selection feature simple set `ListBox.SelectionMode` to `SelectionMode.Multiple`. Why do you want to disbale it? It's a convenience feature to improve the user experience. Usually if multi-select is possible users expect Ctrl+A to be a working hotkey.

Comment: In addition, when handling the preview event that was raised by the ListBox then it does not affect sibling elements like the TextBox. Please provide a minimal example that reproduces your issue. After review, your current code must work, for sure. Also make sure that you don't post malformed code. This makes a code review even harder. We don't know if those are typos or actual errors in your code. Please, be more careful when posting a question. This makes helping you more appealing and easier

Comment: I apologize for not explaining it properly. Exactly the story of a textbox belonging to Listitem in ListBox. And this problem was solved by adding a keyup event when processing the keydown event above. Thank you for your reply.